# ¿Cómo enviar parametros del form de angular a mi petición GET de springboot?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, rest

Tengo un formulario que contiene dos **datepicker** uno para **fecha inicio** y otro par **fecha fin**, lo que quiero es recuperarlos en mi form como tipo Date, y **enviar** esos parametros a mi servicio rest de java a traves de mi peticion GET, para que pueda yo hacer mi consulta con esos filtros de fechas

HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="labels">Fecha inicial: </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fechaInicial" bsDatepicker
                            [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="labels">Fecha final: </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fechaFinal" bsDatepicker
                            [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" (click)="enviar()">Consultar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Tengo el método **enviar()** el cual valida mi formulario y hace el llamado al servicio que cree a traves del metodo **consultarServicio** para hacer la peticion GET, en el cual falta que le pase como parametro las dos fechas tipo Date, otra cosa imprimi en el log la siguiente linea :

> console.log("fecha::: " +this.simpleForm.get('fechaInicial').;

y el resultdo lo pinta asi:

> Mon Apr 19 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central)

asi recupero la fecha que seleccione en el date picker, pero como la asigno a un tipo Date? para mandarla como parametro al servicio, ademas quiero transformar la fecha a este formato **20210419**

COMPONENT.TS

```html
enviar() {
    if (this.simpleForm.valid) {
      console.log("fecha::: " +this.simpleForm.get('fechaInicial').;
      this.service.consultarServicio(FALTA COLOCAR LOS PRAMETROS DE FECHA).subscribe(data=>{
          this.modelConsultarValoresEmision=data;
        })
      

    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        text: 'No es valido'
      })
    }
  }
```

Este es mi service.ts

```html
export class ConsultarInformacionService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  Url = 'http://localhost:8081/consultarInformacion';

  
  consultarServicio(fechaInicial:Date, fechaFinal:Date){
    return this.http.get<Valores[]>(this.Url+"/"+fechaInicial+"/"+fechaFinal);
  }
}
```

y este es mi servicio Rest

```html
@GetMapping
    public List<Valores> consultarValoresParams(@RequestParam (value="fechInicio") int fechInicio, @RequestParam (value="fechFinal")  int fechFinal){
        return valoresService.listarValores(fechInicio, fechFinal); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes transformar la información como tu la requieres con un pipe, lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera...

```
let fechaInicial = this.datepipe.transform(this.simpleForm.get('fechaInicial'), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

despues del if y antes de tu log en COMPONENT.TS y no olvides tu

```
constructor(...private datepipe: DatePipe..){...}
```

no se si funcione el pipe sin las separaciones de `/` pero si no funciona agrega el `/` y después eliminalo con un `.replace`